# Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0203E: Servlet [banners]: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet was found

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I am getting below error in Websphere 7.0.0.39 once i deployed my war file.

> Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0203E: Servlet
>   [banners]: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet was
>   found, but is missing another required class
>
> RVE0206E: This error typically implies that the servlet was originally
>   compiled with classes which cannot be located by the server.
>   SRVE0187E: Check your class path to ensure that all classes required
>   by the servlet are present.SRVE0210I: This problem can be debugged by
>   recompiling the servlet using only the classes in the application's
>   runtime class path SRVE0234I: Application class
>   path=[/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib/dt.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib/htmlconverter.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib/ibmorbtools.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib/jconsole.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib/tools.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/bannersites/classes:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/classes:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/EJBCommandTarget.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/IVTClient.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/OTiSConvertTime.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/activation-impl.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/aspectjrt.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/bsf-engines.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/cimgr.ops.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/commandlineutils.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/commons-discovery.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/databeans.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/ffdcSupport.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/htmlshell.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/installver.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/installxml.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/iscdeploy.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/ivblogbr.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/j2ee.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/jNative2ascii.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/jacl.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/jrom.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/jsf-nls.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/launchclient.jar:/app/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/lmproxy.jar:/app/usr

Comment: You are either missing some dependent jars, or you have compiled your classes with later JDK that is supported on WAS. Remember that WAS v7 runs on JDK 1.6, and you cannot run application compiled with 1.7 there. Also check SystemOut and ffdc logs, you should find somewhere there what class is missing.

Comment: As Gas said, SystemOut will almost certainly have a ClassNotFoundException that will tell you what specific class is missing.  If it's a WebSphere class, it may be something that's not visible to apps, so you may need to add it to your application along with your other jars.  I'm not positive of the logic WebSphere uses to get to that message, so be on the lookout for other exception types as well.